# Wireshark display filter for Protocol != 802.11

Tags: wireshark

I've set Wireshark's capture filter set to capture only packets from the MAC address of interest, but the result is dominated by zillions of packets whose Protocol is "802.11".  I want to view all of the packets that are NOT 802.11, e.g. ARP, DCHP, DNS, TCP, etc.

For example, in the following, I'd like to hide all of the 802.11 packets and show the DHCP packets (and any others that are NOT 802.11):

[image]

I tried "wlan.fc.type != 0", but clearly that's not correct.  What's the magic keyword for such a filter?

### update

@ChristopherMaynard's comment is close, and I now understand that a simple filter of:

```
ip
```

is almost what I want, but it fails to display packets of type ARP, EAPOL, LLC, MDP and perhaps others.

Comment: Downvotes do convey some information, so I'm not against them.  But it sure would be nice to get some actionable info along with the downvote!  (FYI, I've searched online docs, cheat sheets, tutorials.  I simply don't know the name of the filter.)

Comment: I think your question is off-topic on SO, and should be on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireshark

Comment: Ah!  Okay.  But I note that there are LOTS of other Wireshark questions here on SO, which is what emboldened me to post it here.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Have you tried `dhcp` as a display filter for only displaying DHCP packets?  If you want DHCP and ARP packets, try `dhcp or arp`.  DHCP, ARP and TCP - try `dhcp or arp or tcp`.  DNS too?  How about `dhcp or arp or tcp or dns`?  

Curious about all possible display filters?  Have a look at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/.  Need even more information on Wireshark display filters?  Have a look at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard - My challenge is that I want *any* packet that's not 802.11 -- I don't know what they'll be in advance.  A simple filter of `ip` comes close, but doesn't show MDP, ARP, LLC, EAPOL packets (and likely others).

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  You can use `!wlan` to exclude all 802.11 packets, but that hardly seems like it'll be useful.  If you want to exclude 802.11 management frames, then maybe `wlan and !(wlan.fc.type == 0)` is what you're after?  Have a look at this cheatsheet?: https://www.semfionetworks.com/uploads/2/9/8/3/29831147/wireshark_802.11_filters_-_reference_sheet.pdf

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard > I don't understand what you want. 
I apologize for not being clearer: In the column labeled "Protocol", I want to hide any entry labeled "802.11" and display everything else.   Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard: I did look at that cheatsheet before posting the OP.  Evidently I'm handicapped by not knowing the distinction between management, control and data frames.

Comment: If you just want data frames but those without un-dissected data (which would still show 802.11 in the Protocol column), then you could try `wlan.fc.type == 2 and !data`.  Or you could try `!(frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan:data" or frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan")`?

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard yes - !(frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan:data" or frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan")? was the winning ticket.  Want to make an answer out of it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Converted comment to answer and added an alternate solution while I'm at it.]*

If you just want data frames but those without un-dissected data (which would still show 802.11 in the Protocol column), then you could try `wlan.fc.type == 2 and !data`. Or you could try `!(frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan:data" or frame.protocols == "radiotap:wlan_radio:wlan")`.

Another alternative is to download the [filtcols.lua](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/editor-wiki/-/wikis/Lua/Examples/filtcols) script written by Chuck Craft, save it to your plugins directory (Wireshark: *Help -> About Wireshark -> Folders -> Personal Lua Plugins*), the [re]start Wireshark.  Now you can apply a display filter such as `wlan and !(filtcols.protocol == "802.11")`.

Comment: That is so stupid. *sigh*